# How to import flutter .dart configuration file into a package or main project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following project flutter project structure:

[image: Flutter project structure]

I want to be able to import `config.dart` into my `authentication_reposotory` (or wherever I need it), but can't import it. Import throws an error suggesting that the path does not exists.

I have tried:

1. Add it as asses in the `pubsec/yaml`, but it complains about `config/` (or `../config/`) not existing:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - config/
```

2. Used a relative path like `../../config/config.dart` or `../config/config.dart`
3. Since `config.dart` is just a file with constant strings, I tried to exported as a class/package.

None of them worked for me, Flutter is not able to find the paths. I manage to make it work inside my `lib` folder by moving the config folder inside of it, but I would like it to be in root project so all of packages and `lib` can have access to it. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With the project structure you provided in your screenshot, you should be able to access config.dart with the following code:

```dart
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("config/config.dart");
```

(And adding config/ as an asset directory in pubspec.yaml, as you did correctly)

However I am wondering what kind of config file you are trying to achieve with a .dart extention. Since dart files outside of the lib folder are not compiled, you can't use things like constants and classes in an uncompiled dart file. You would need to read the data variable (in the code snippet above) as a string, and extract the values from the string etc. So I am not sure if this is what you wanted...